# page navigation in adobe air 4.6

Tags: apache-flex, air

how to naviaget one mxml page to another via  action script

the navigatTourl() method used for webpages but, if want to navigate another mxml page mean how to show

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When creating a Flex Application, the page analogy does not work very well.  In an HTML site, each page is a self contained entity with no real relation to any other page.  However, a Flex Application is a single self contained entity; and that entity can have lots of screens, or views.

To navigate between views in a Flex Application there are a lot of ways.  Here are three approaches:

1. You could use [States](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7fb4.html)
2. You could use a [Navigator container](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7fb9.html), such as a ViewStack or a TabNavigator.
3. You could toggle the [visible](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/core/UIComponent.html#visible) property of your UI Components.

Generally, the first two options would be used for massive changes.  The third option would be used for minor changes.